# JavaScript Array[1] get content

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am stepping through the AngularJS code below in the debugger. It says testingWhat is of type Array[1], but when I try to access it using [0], testingArray becomes of type undefined, with no content. Why?

```
myApp.controller('SomeController', function ($scope, MyData) {
    $scope.dataForTheTree = MyData.collection;
    var testingWhat = MyData.collection;
    var testingArray = MyData.collection[0];
    for(var x in testingWhat) {
        console.log("Loading data into tree: " + x);
    }
});
```

Comment: You could have an undefined value in the array ... MyData.collection[0] could be undefined depending on how the data was loaded

Comment: The first content is an Array[20]. The type description is 0: Array[20]

Comment: does using a for(var i = 0; i<MyData.collection.length;i++){...} work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If console.log(testingArray) is undefined then the first object in the collection is undefined .. you essentially have an array like:

```
var array = [undefined];
```

It will have a length .. array[0] will be undefined.

On another note, never ever use `for in` to iterate over an array. It could iterate over properties of the array or you could get the items in the wrong order.

Always use the for loop. [Here is a more detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/5246):